# Activator command not working

Tags: java, playframework, activator

I wanted to install the play framework today.

So I went to the download page https://www.playframework.com/download here and downloaded the Play with Activator zip file Activator 1.3.12 including Play 2.5.13 (671M).

After that, I extracted it, and added the extracted `activator-dist-1.3.12` directory to the path in the enviroment variables. 
So according to the download page, I should now be able to use commands like

```
activator new
```

or

```
activator ui
```

But none of them are working. It seems like my command window can't find the activator command. What did I do wrong, or what did I forget ?

**Edit: **

This is the error message I get from the command line: The command "activator" is either spelled wrong or could not be found.
I am using Windows 10 if that helps. The java version I am using is 1.8.0_111.

This is my path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Livestreamer;C:\Users\Stefan\JEE\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Studium\6.Sem\bin;%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Play\activator-dist-1.3.12
```

One thing I noticed is that, normally the PATH System variable is written completely in capital letters. Mine isn't it's just written normally.

Comment: Please provide more information about your error and your configuration : [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok I see. I try making my question more clear. What do you mean with configuration?

Comment: You should provide your complete `PATH` configuration and the complete error you have so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands are in the subfolder `bin`. Update your path to point to `activator-dist-1.3.12\bin` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload (close and open) your terminal (command window), so it will catch up the changes you did to the environment variables.

Comment: I did that. Several times. I also checked if the changes I made to the enviroment variables are still there.